# How to delete a Sonatype Nexus OSS(3) Component from a Repository

Tags: repository, nexus, sonatype

its my first question here and i try to do my best. :-)
If there should be something wrong, tell me simply and I correct myself.

Im new to Sonatypes Nexus 3 OSS, and i cant find a way to delete a component from my repository.

A package from my repository has become useless and now I would like to delete it. The artefacts I deleted already, but the package remains.

I use the web ui and I think that I just missing something.

Update: You find the page that show the packages in: Browse > Components > the-empty-package

Thanks in advance!

LocX

EDIT-1: This is the package i want to delete. There are no assets in it.

[image: The package i want to delete.]

Comment: You should specify what kind of artifacts you're talking about. Nexus can dozens of different types, and there are bugs for some and not others.

Comment: I prefer to remove any artifacts, but the package in which they were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.0.0-03 version, there is a new "Delete Component" button. In the 3.0.0 Version the button to delete the package was missing.

Answer (score 2):

This is documented with screenshots in their book. See https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/using.html#asset-information.
[image: Nexus 3.0 screenshot]
Note the "Delete asset" button on the top left.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, their bug tracker is at https://issues.sonatype.org/projects/NEXUS/issues. Fixes are slow if they haven't been told it's broken.

Comment: I prefer to remove any artifacts. On top of the screenshot you posted, called the artifact Junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar and I mean the package Junit on the left of it.
If you delete all artefacts in a package, the package remains.