# How to delete a Sonatype Nexus OSS(3) Component from a Repository?

Tags: maven-2, nexus, nexus3

I recently installed the Sonatype OSS 3.14.0-04.  I new to nexus and I am creating roles stuff.  I have seen nexus 2, but I did not have any involvement in setting it up or administrative work.  What I seem to be having issues with now is deleting assets as the default admin.  I added a package to the hosted maven-snapshot repo and I want to delete it using the GUI.  When I click on Browse this is all I see.  I did read the old post here in stackoverflow [How to delete a Sonatype Nexus OSS(3) Component from a Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332672/how-to-delete-a-sonatype-nexus-oss3-component-from-a-repository).  But the user was able to see The components under browse.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click into the repository you uploaded it to, you should get a list view of all components and assets within that repository.

If you click on the item you want to delete or if it's a folder, the contents of the folder you should be able to delete them from there.

See https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Browsing+Repositories+and+Repository+Groups for more information (specifically the last screenshot shows the delete asset button).